# I don't know only first element getting picked up by my sql query

Tags: sqlite

I am using sqlite3. I am working on IMDB database. I want to extract the movies with a rating of 10.0 but it's only giving me the first result. Although, I can extract the movie_id but can't reproduce the title.

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE movies (
                    id INTEGER,
                    title TEXT NOT NULL,
                    year NUMERIC,
                    PRIMARY KEY(id)
                );
CREATE TABLE stars (
                movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                person_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id),
                FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES people(id)
            );
CREATE TABLE directors (
                movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                person_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id),
                FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES people(id)
            );
CREATE TABLE ratings (
                movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                rating REAL NOT NULL,
                votes INTEGER NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id)
            );
CREATE TABLE people (
                id INTEGER,
                name TEXT NOT NULL,
                birth NUMERIC,
                PRIMARY KEY(id)
            );
sqlite> SELECT movie_id from ratings WHERE rating = 10.0;
movie_id
10176328
10342460
10544422
10716326
10914342
11099860
2632430
2633610
3525174
5390098
8035236
8563656
sqlite> SELECT title FROM movies WHERE id = (SELECT movie_id from ratings WHERE rating = 10.0);
title
Exteriores: Mulheres Brasileiras na Diplomacia
sqlite> SELECT title FROM movies where id = '10176328';
title
Exteriores: Mulheres Brasileiras na Diplomacia
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `in` instead of an equality condition:

```
SELECT m.title 
FROM movies m
WHERE m.id IN (SELECT r.movie_id from ratings r WHERE r.rating = 10.0)
```

That is because the subquery does return more that one row. In many databases, this would generate a runtime error, however it seems like sqlite is flex enough to handle this without error (but still not doing what you want).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative that may be more efficient than `IN` is to use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT m.title 
FROM movies AS m
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ratings AS r WHERE r.rating = 10.0 AND r.movie_id = m.id)
```